Why do JetBrains Mono Nerd Font settings look different in Fish terminal across systems?
I'm using the JetBrains Mono Nerd Font in the Fish shell terminal on two different systems. Both have the same font size and terminal configuration:

Font settings:

Terminal: Fish shell

Font: JetBrains Mono Nerd Font

Size: 13px

Terminal emulator:  Wezterm


MacOS:

Arch Wsl:

Despite the identical settings, the font's appearance and clarity seem different between the systems. It feels like one is sharper or more legible than the other.
What could be causing this discrepancy?  Could it be related to differences in font rendering engines, DPI settings, or something else?
Any guidance would be appreciated.
I tried the following to ensure the font renders identically across systems:

Verified that both systems use the same terminal emulator and Fish shell version.

Checked that the font files for JetBrains Mono Nerd Font are identical on both systems.

Adjusted anti-aliasing, sub-pixel rendering, and font smoothing settings in the terminal emulator.

Ensured that DPI and display scaling settings are consistent on both systems.


I expected the font to render with the same clarity and sharpness on both systems, but the appearance remains noticeably different.
